# Making a table column narrower (tabu)

Tags: tables, tabu

I'm using tabu for creating a table, however I can't seem to find the way to make the two left columns narrower and the most right one wider for text.

The code I'm using is:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Kepler orbit parameters}
    \begin{tabu}{*{3}{X[c]}}
        \toprule
        Parameter & Name & Description \\
         \midrule
         a & semi-major axis & The axis that coincides with both focus points of the ellipse \\
         E & Eccentric Anomaly & The angle between the center of equivalent circle with radius $r$ \\
         \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
    \label{tab:Kepler}
\end{table}
```

I want to keep the two leftmost columns centered, and the right one wider and not centered so the text will be easier to read.
Any suggestions?

Comment: don't use the tabu package, it is buggy and unmaintained. See the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Comment: Is there another package that can create the same style as I'm using here? with the horizontal lines?

Comment: well personally I manage all tabulars with tabular or sometimes tabularx. But you can also check the new tabularray.

Comment: Something like `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llX}` should work perfectly fine for this kind of table as there really is no need to allow line breaks in the first two columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Ulrike Fischer in the comment, the `tabu` package should be avoided. You may use the relatively new [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package. (You will find similarities between `tabu` and `tabularray` packages.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} %to use booktabs rules 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Kepler orbit parameters}
    \begin{tblr}{
        width = {\textwidth}, %width of the table
        colspec = {@{}ccX[l]@{}}, %column types
        rows = {m} %vertical alignment
    }
        \toprule
        Parameter & Name & Description \\
        \midrule
        a & semi-major axis & The axis that coincides with both focus points of the ellipse \\
        E & Eccentric Anomaly & The angle between the center of equivalent circle with radius $r$ \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Any chance you can explain the column types line ```colspec = {@{}ccX[l]@{}}```?

Comment: The `c` columns are centered columns (i.e. their contents are centered) and their width is loosely equal to the width of the content. The `X` column is like fixed-width column where the width is automatically calculated. `@{}`s are used to remove the spaces before the first column and after the last column.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest that you employ a `tabularx` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Kepler orbit parameters\strut}\label{tab:Kepler}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} llL @{}}
      \toprule
      Parameter & Name & Description \\
      \midrule
      $a$ & semi-major axis & The axis that coincides with both focus points of the ellipse \\
      $E$ & Eccentric Anomaly & The angle between the center of equivalent circle with radius $r$ \\
      \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

just for nostalgia, an example using `tabu`, of course it is no longer viable to use it, as mentioned it has some errors since the implementation was not finished and the package has been abandoned for a long time, even it is no longer possible to shade the cells , but at the time it was very useful to me since I could manipulate the width of the tables, the cells and their distribution relative to factors, in addition to manipulating styles it allowed me to make tables with a better style than those made in the office suite, or other similar WYSIWYG. Unfortunately I used this package for a long time until the **cell shading bug**, and I have only recently used the traditional packages so I don't know if they can reach styles like the ones that tabu can do since I currently make more serious texts that they don't use colorful styles but clean and readable. As always it is a matter of taste.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % to rotate text
%Ex-Package for beautifull tables.
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{002fa7}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \def\TableLineSize{3pt}   
        \tabulinesep = 5pt 
        \tabulinestyle{\TableLineSize myblue}
        \caption{Kepler orbit parameters\strut}\label{tab:Kepler}
        \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {|X[1cm]|X[3cm]|X[20lm]|} %note cm is center+middle.
            %tabu sintax X column "|" to indicate vertical line.
            %X[Relative_to_total_factor+horizontal_align(l,c,r)+Vertical_align(m,b,p)], example : 3bm, 0.5lb, etc.
            \tabucline - % Lines musrt be defined using \tabucline. but not in discontinous line.
             \rotatebox{90}{Parameter} & Name & Description \\ \tabucline - 
            $a$ & semi-major axis & The axis that coincides with both focus points of the ellipse \\ \tabucline[0.5pt,myblue] -
            $E$ & Eccentric Anomaly & The angle between the center of equivalent circle with radius $r$ \\ \tabucline -     
        \end{tabu}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (which is similar the classical `{tabular}`  but with more functionnalities).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Kepler orbit parameters\strut}\label{tab:Kepler}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}llX[l]@{}}
      \toprule
      Parameter & Name & Description \\
      \midrule
      $a$ & semi-major axis & The axis that coincides with both focus points of the ellipse \\
      $E$ & Eccentric Anomaly & The angle between the center of equivalent circle with radius $r$ \\
      \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]